# list<item: float> not supported in join non-key field?

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am trying to join 2 Arrow tables where some columns are of `list<float>` data type. Note that my join columns/keys are primitive data types and some my non-join columns/keys are of `list<float>`. But, PyArrow `join()` cannot join such as table, although pandas can. It says

```
ArrowInvalid: Data type list<item: float> is not supported in join non-key field
```

when I execute this piece of code

```
joined_table = table_1.join(table_2, ['k1', 'k2', 'k3'])
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue or get around this would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think currently PyArrow join doesn't support some column types. See criteria for allowed types here: https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/cpp/src/arrow/compute/exec/hash_join_node.cc#L48

I believe the issue is (but I might be wrong) that list is not a fixed-width type and cannot be processed currently. You might want to [open a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARROW/issues) about this.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-17216